# Caching login forms with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, http-caching

I have a Rails 3 website, for which the home page is static content plus a login form. I want to use **HTTP caching** on this page (we’re on Heroku - behind Varnish), but then the login form's authenticity token is cached which triggers forgery protection and prevents login for all but the first session.

I *think* my best course of action is to disable forgery protection for this action but first I want to understand the risks involved.

So… **what are the risks of disabling forgery protection in this scenario?**

Alternatively, is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad things could happen, theres a reason CSRF is on by default.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Forging_login_requests

Comment: Thanks, but the wiki article is a bit scant on detail. The specific scenario mentioned is not an issue in this case. Can you flesh out any other scenarios?

Comment: Theres a reason its on by default as an added layer of security, dont cache the page and use CSRF protection. Lets put it this way, of you disable CSRF what would stop someone from making a fake login page and using the same form that you use? Your website would accept the parameters, the users get sent to your site. No one knows that an account has been compromised.

Comment: @DevinM, I don't think this is the issue here. Someone can always make a fake login page and collect credentials through it. CSRF is about doing (possible malicious) actions on a logged in user's behalf, without his intention and possibly even without him being aware of it as it happens.